# MySQL find_in_set to find the number of ad numbers for the category?

Tags: mysql

How can I get the number of advertisements when linking tables with left join in Mysql?

[SQL-FIDDLE-TABLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cde7eb/1)

if I use count (*) and group by, I get a result like

[SQL-FIDDLE-TABLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cde7eb/2)

```
count
2
2
2
```

My goal is to get the number of ads with Find_in_set

[SQL-FIDDLE-TABLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cde7eb/3)

result:

```
count
2
```

Result count: 2, but there are 1 classifieds in that category. How can I get the number of ads for a category?

Comment: I solved the problem. Thanks anyway.

select count(*) from (
 select
  ads_category.id as category_id,
  ads_category.title,
  ads.id,
  ads.categories,
  ads.ads_title
  from ads_category left join ads
 on FIND_IN_SET(ads_category.id,ads.categories)
 where ads.id IS NOT NULL
 group by ads.id
) as table_1
where FIND_IN_SET(1,table_1.categories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIND_IN_SET() doesn't return the number of elements in a list, it just returns the position of a specific value, if it is found.

One expression you can use to calculate the length of a list is:

```
LENGTH(ads.categories)-LENGTH(REPLACE(ads.categories, ',', ''))+1
```

The difference in the length of the string and the string with commas removed, plus on, is the number of elements.

But you will find storing data as a comma-separated list when you really want to treat the elements individually is going to [cause more problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574).

It'll be much easier if you represent this many-to-many relationship between ads and categories by creating a third table to store each pair of `ads.id` and `ads_category.id`.